# Struts 1 Login Page always returns 404

Tags: forms, authentication, struts1

I have managed to get into my login page, but once I supply my credentials and want to go to the success page, I always get a 404.

my struts-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">


<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="LoginForm" type="com.myselflearning.MyActionForm"/>

    </form-beans>

    <global-exceptions>

    </global-exceptions>

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
        <action input="/login.jsp" name="LoginForm" path="/login" scope="session" validate="true" type="com.myselflearning.MyAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" redirect="true" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" redirect="true" />
        </action>
        <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>

    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>

    <message-resources parameter="MessageResource"/>

    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property
            property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
    </plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcomeStruts.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        </jsp-config>
    </web-app>
```

N.B. I am putting my action and ActionForm classes together to save space :D

```
package com.myselflearning;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class MyAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        MyActionForm myActionForm = (MyActionForm) (form);

        if (myActionForm.getUsername().equals(myActionForm.getPassword())) {
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        } else {
            return mapping.findForward("failure");
        }

    }

}
```

package com.myselflearning;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;

```
public class MyActionForm extends ActionForm {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8713356513481803825L;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public ActionErrors validate (ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        if (username == null || username.trim().equals(""))
        {
            errors.add("username", new ActionMessage("error.username"));
        }

        if (password == null || password.trim().equals(""))
        {
            errors.add("password", new ActionMessage("error.passworld"));
        }

        return errors;
    }

    public MyActionForm()
    {
        super();
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }   


}
```

I probably haven't done struts for long enough (also, have a requirement to be with 1.1), but it seems something very small, but fundamental has gone wrong.

All I am trying to see is the success.jsp page once I verify my credentials.

Any help is appreciated, kindest regards,

Comment: Is there a `success.jsp` page? Also note misspelling of `passworld` in your property name.

Comment: Yes there is a success.jsp page.......It simply says "Good job!"...that's why I didn't put it in there...